# Why doesn't the class take the info from list? Python

Tags: python, list, class, methods

So I'm trying to get info from a txt file into a list while using a class. The problem is that when I try to tell the class to fetch the attributes it does not take the info from the tuples in the list instead, it just tells me the info assigned to the given number.

Bellow is the main part of the code. So when I call Portray it should append a tuple to slst as a Notas object. The problem, instead of counting the whole Notas(ranlst[1],ranlst[2],tranlst[3]) as an object it takes every input as one. So, in the example bellow it should print:
Charles 70 4h

But instead, it prints:
Charles Charles Charles.

The info in the file is stored as follows:

Charles

70

4h

Any idea why this happens?

```
class Notas:
    def __init__(self,nom,temp,nota):
        self.nom=nom
        self.temp=temp
        self.nota=nota

def Portray(): 
        file=open(path,'r',encoding='UTF8').readlines()
        lines=[line.strip()for line in file]
        ranlst=[]
        for part in lines:
          for leni in range(3):
            ranlst.append(str(part))
            slst.append(Notas(ranlst[0],ranlst[1],ranlst[2]))
          ranlst=[]
        print(slst[0].nom,slst[0].nota,slst[0].temp)
```

Comment: Try some of the techniques in the [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) article or similar?

Comment: `slst` is not defined?  Also how would `ranlst` have all 3 elements populated in the initial run?  The code provided doesn't produce `Charles Charles Charles` as output.  Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: BTW, I think the program you posted is somewhat different from the program you ran, so be sure to debug the version you're actually testing.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Notas:
    def __init__(self,nom,temp,nota):
        self.nom=nom
        self.temp=temp
        self.nota=nota

def Portray(): 
        file=open(path,'r',encoding='UTF8').readlines()
        lines=[line.strip()for line in file]
        ranlst=[]
        for part in lines:
          for leni in range(3):
            ranlst.append(str(part)) ## HERE
            slst.append(Notas(ranlst[0],ranlst[1],ranlst[2]))
          ranlst=[]
        print(slst[0].nom,slst[0].nota,slst[0].temp)
```

HERE statement runs 3 times. But str(part) is not changing because it is outer for loop. So, ranlst[0] [1] [2] are the same. And that's why you are getting 3 Charles'. You may switch those two fors like this.

```
for leni in range(3):
    for part in lines:
```